# Coroutines in Scheme (R5RS)

Tags: lua, scheme, coroutine, callcc

So I first came across the concept of coroutines in lua and lua's implementation was more or less understandable.. I'm learning scheme now and I understand that the same functionality is implemented with call/cc, but I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around how exactly one would go about achieving this. Anyone know an easy tutorial or something on the subject?

Answer (score 1):

Matt Might has written a good introduction to continuations, including a section on coroutines:

http://matt.might.net/articles/programming-with-continuations--exceptions-backtracking-search-threads-generators-coroutines/